# increase the size of array deque

Tags: python-3.x, arraydeque

I'm trying to be as efficient as possible with space while creating an array based deque. So, the array starts with size one, and I'll call a function called "grow" if the array is not large enough when I push new values to the deque (at either end). I then mod to preserve the front and back of the deque. Here is a sample of what I've done so far:

```
def __init__(self):
# capacity starts at 1; we will grow on demand.
  self.__capacity = 1
  self.__contents = [None] * self.__capacity
  self.__front = 1
  self.__back = 1
  self.__size = 1

def __grow(self):
  old_list = self.__contents
  walk = self.__front
  for k in range(self.__capacity):
    self.__contents[k] = old_list[walk]
    walk = (1 + walk) % len(old_list)
  self.__front = 0
  self.__capacity = self.__capacity * 2

def push_front(self, val):
  if self.__size == len(self.__contents):
    self.__grow(self.__capacity)
  self.__front = (self.__front - 1) % len(self.__contents)
  self.__contents[self.__front] = val
  self.__size += 1
```

My question comes when I call the grow method. I keep getting the error that I am giving 'grow' two positional arguments, but I don't see where or how that's happening. If anyone has any ideas on how to improve this so that it only has one positional argument? Also, does my reasoning for a walk through to re-index in the grow method make sense as well as my reasoning for the push front method?

Comment: First thing I would like to suggest is that don't start length ( `self.__capacity = 1`) with one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an argument to __grow if you are going to pass arguments to it, i.e.:

```
def __grow(self, size):
```

Currently, it only has a self argument, but you are also passing in self.__capacity when you call it. However, I think you really meant to call grow without arguments:

```
if self.__size == len(self.__contents):
  self.__grow()
```

Answer (score 0):

All instance methods in a class treat the calling instance as their first argument, unless you use the class to call the method in which case you must provide an instance as the first argument.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f(self, x):
        print(self, x)

a = A()
a.f(1)    # <A object at 0x7fa9a067da90> 1
A.f(a, 2) # <A object at 0x7fa9a067da90> 2
```

So when you call `self.__grow(self.__capacity)`, that gets turned into `Deque.__grow(self, self.__capacity)`. But your `__grow` method only takes `self`.